# Grouping and summarizing by keeping other columns in R

Tags: r, grouping

I have a dataframe which I am grouping using the group_by function, and summarizing it with using the summarize function in R.

```
MM_group<-group_by(SYC,Method,Maturity)
```

My dataset looks like this,

```
 Year           Group  County Seed.Brand Seed.Variety Seed.Maturity
1 2014 Group 0 No-till Yankton     Asgrow       AG0832           0.8
2 2014 Group 0 No-till   Brown     Asgrow       AG0934           0.9
3 2014 Group 0 No-till   Brown     Asgrow       AG0934           0.9
4 2014 Group 0 No-till   Brown     Asgrow       AG0934           0.9
5 2014 Group 0 No-till   Brown    Pioneer        90Y90           0.9
6 2014 Group 0 No-till   Brown     Asgrow       AG0934           0.9

Yield  Method Maturity digits
1 73.23 No-till        0      0
2 65.14 No-till        0      0
3 63.63 No-till        0      0
4 61.57 No-till        0      0
5 60.20 No-till        0      0
```

I am grouping by Method & Maturity. I am trying to get County and Year for maximum yield for the Method & Maturity combination.

I have done the following:

```
summarize(MM_group,Max_Yield=max(Yield))

       Method Maturity Max_Yield
           <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>
1      Irrigated        0    69.600
2      Irrigated        1    86.013
3      Irrigated        2    88.750
4      Irrigated        3    79.650
5        No-till        0    79.470
6        No-till        1    79.856
7        No-till        2    85.860
8        No-till        3    68.530
9  Non-irrigated        0    83.210
10 Non-irrigated        1    81.916
11 Non-irrigated        2   103.740
12 Non-irrigated        3    94.410
```

But, this doesn't give me the county name and year. I know I can use cbind or joins to get that data but wondering if there is another easier way of doing this.

Expected Output:

```
          Method Maturity Max_Yield  Year                  Group
           <chr>    <chr>     <dbl> <int>                 <fctr>
1      Irrigated        0    69.600  2012 Group 0 or 1 Irrigated
2      Irrigated        1    86.013  2012 Group 0 or 1 Irrigated
3      Irrigated        2    88.750  2013 Group 2 or 3 Irrigated
4      Irrigated        3    79.650  2013 Group 2 or 3 Irrigated
5        No-till        0    79.470  2013        Group 0 No-till
6        No-till        1    79.856  2012        Group 1 No-till
7        No-till        2    85.860  2013        Group 2 No-till
8        No-till        3    68.530  2014        Group 3 No-till
9  Non-irrigated        0    83.210  2013  Group 0 Non-irrigated
10 Non-irrigated        1    81.916  2012  Group 1 Non-irrigated
11 Non-irrigated        2   103.740  2014  Group 2 Non-irrigated
12 Non-irrigated        3    94.410  2014  Group 3 Non-irrigated
```

Comment: http://www.sdsoybean.org/programs-events/yield-contest/ you should be able to find the entire dataset here

Comment: From that link, where is the data ?  Is it the Agronomic data?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But, my data is a compilation of all the years.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
summarize(MM_group, 
          rank = which.max(Yield),
          Year_rank = Year[rank],
          County_rank = County[rank])
```

Comment: This works like a charm! This is what I was looking for. Great way to use the rank function like an index.

Comment: @Kasi I'm not using the function *rank*, it is just the name of a new column, you could use *foo* instead, it would still work. And I think the name *rank* is a bad choice of name, my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

We can use

```
SYC %>%
   group_by(Method, Maturity) %>%
   slice(which.max(Yield)) %>% 
   rename(Max_Yield = Yield) %>%
   select(Method, Maturity, Max_Yield, Year, Group)
```

Comment: That won't work cause I need maximum yield by method and maturity column. Your method is basically grouping the four attributes and finding the maximum. I am trying to just add the county and year columns. Something like this:`test<-left_join(MM_max,Data,by=c('Method'='Method','Maturity'='Maturity','Max_Yield'='Yield'))`.

Comment: @Kasi I also had another method.  It is not clear based on your small example what should be the expected output.  Suppose you have the same 'Method' for each 'County', 'Year', then `left_join` would not work

Comment: @Kasi Please show a small reproducible example and expected output instead of just 4 lines

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `arrange` and `slice` method as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(Method, Maturity, desc(Yield)) %>% 
  group_by(Method, Maturity) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(Method, Maturity, Yield, Year, Group) %>%
  rename(Max_Yield = Yield)
```